# Clothing store changing room dialogue

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, sentence-construction

So I've noticed there is usually a limit of how many pieces of clothing you bring in the changing room nowadays in clothing stores. I wonder what the staff usually say to the customers when the number of clothes they bring in exceeds the maximum.

Do the staff say like...?

> you can only bring in up to 3 items of clothing

As a non native English speaking person, I’d like to know what sentences would sound natural in this case! Thanks

Comment: It varies quite widely depending on the store and its policies. I've encountered "You've got too many items; you'll have to leave some here" or "There's a max[imum] of «whatever the number is»" or "That's too many items". Some stores state a limit, but don't bother to enforce it, as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to express this idea using “natural,” conversational English.

> - ✔️ **Yes:** That’s too many pieces. The limit is three.
> - ✔️ **Yes:** Sorry, you can’t bring {in} that many items. No more than three.
> - ✔️ **Yes:** Only three items, sorry.
> - ✔️ **Yes:** Just three items at a time. Store policy.
> - ✔️ **Yes:** Sorry, Sir (or Madam), we have a max of three items.

There are many ways to express this idea.  In everyday conversation, you should expect to hear sentence fragments and sentences that aren’t grammatically “complete”:

> - Maybe: “Sorry, three, Max.”

Answer (score 0):

As explained in the comment, "sound natural" has two components here, and thus the question becomes difficult to answer. Many variations are correct grammar; but, however, would not sound correct in the context of that particular store or situation. The most natural-sounding would be a polite statement of the store policy.